# Removing items older than x from localStorage (Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, local-storage

I have a state in the reducer, that is built in the following way:

`state = {
    companies: ['company1', 'company2', 'company3', 'company4']
}`

These companies are fetched from API and added to the state.

And I would like to remove from localStorage only the companies which were added to the state x hours before or earlier. How should I properly approach this task?

My localStorage.js:

```
export const loadState = () => {
  try {
    const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state')
    if (serializedState === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return JSON.parse(serializedState)
  } catch (err) {
    return undefined
  }
}

export const saveState = (state) => {
  try {
    const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state)
    localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState)
  } catch (err) {
    // to define
  }
}
```

saving in state happens in redcuer's CASE that looks like this:

```
case FETCH_FROM_API:
  return {
    ...state,
    companies: [payload, ...state.companies]
  };
```

Comment: No way to do that if you don't store a timestamp for each item when you add it or have something coming from back end that tells you anything about age. LocalStorage API has nothing related to time stored

Comment: So do you think that storing a timestamp for every record would be a good idea or is there any better, more automatic solution?

Comment: More automatic...not likely

Comment: I see, thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: As @charlietfl said timestamp is must,otherwise you need to get API call with continuous polling.Also redesign tour STATE,keeping normalize it

Comment: Yes exactly, thanks guys to your guidance and the further search I made - I'm going to add a timestamp in Action Creator and hope it works the way I want :)